# Extracting data from CustomerOrder to display as total sales data

Tags: java, playframework

In an admin page of my Play Framework app,I need to list the `Product`s sold between two dates and display the `Product name`,`quantity` sold and total `price`.I have modelled this info in a `CustomerOrder` model.Still I am having some doubts as to which data structure I should use to hold these above mentioned data.

The Admin is supposed to be able to list the sales data in a table format as below

---

```
Product Name | quantity | total amount received
===================================================
flwr vase#12 |    13     |  1250
---------------------------------------------------
lampshade#3  |    11     |   110
-----------------------------------------
```

I thought of writing a method in `Admin` class which gets the `CustomerOrder`s between the two dates,and was stuck at extracting the info from `CustomerOrder`.
Each product name should be a primary key of the table ,I guess.So I can create a map with the product name as key.Then what should be the value?As I iterate thru each `CustomerOrder`,I should increment the quantity of each product sold and total amount received should be updated.

The total amount is `order.cartitem.qty*order.cartitem.product.price + order.tax+ order.shipping` ..and I think this makes the loop a bit complicated...Can someone advise how I can do this?

```
public void allSalesData(Date start,Date end){
    List<CustomerOrder> orders = CustomerOrder.find("select o  from CustomerOrder o where o.orderDate between :startdate and :enddate").bind("startdate",start).bind("enddate",end).fetch();
    //now how to extract? should I use a map ?
}

import play.db.jpa.Model;
class CustomerOrder extends Model{
    ...
    public Customer customer;
    public Date orderDate;
    public Set<OrderItem> orderItems;
    public BigDecimal tax;
    public BigDecimal shipping;
   ...
}

class OrderItem extends Model {

    public Product product;
    public int quantity;
}

class Product extends Model{
    public String name;
    public BigDecimal price;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to display exactly? Do you need to list each item with quantity, price and total?

Comment: I need to list each product,qty sold and total money earned from it

Comment: check the updated answer with tax and shipping

Comment: @emt14 thanks for the reply..but I realised a flaw in my thinking ..The tax and shipping are calculated for each instance of a CustomerOrder ,not for each Product..So I don't think it  is right  to add them to total price of Product instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is to aggregate the all the products from your list of customer orders and the corresponding quantities.
You should iterate through your CustomerOrders and order Items and place each product in a map and increase the corresponding quantity.

You could do something like:

```
public void allSalesData(Date start,Date end){

    List orders = CustomerOrder.find("select o  from CustomerOrder o where o.orderDate between :startdate and :enddate").bind("startdate",start).bind("enddate",end).fetch();

    Map prodMap = new HashMap();
    Map priceMap = new HashMap();
   Integer quantity = null;
   Long price = null;
   for(CustomerOrder cusOrder: orders) {
      for(OrderItem item: cusOrder.orderItems){
          quantity = prodMap.get(item.product);
          prodMap.put(item.product, quantity + item.quantity);
          price = priceMap.get(item.product);
          priceMap.put(item.product, quantity * item.price cusOrder.tax + cusOrder.shipping + price);
      }
   }

  render(prodMap, priceMap);
}
```

Then iterate in your template through the map and show the product name, price, quantity and quantity * price.